# How to get Windows DNS suffix search list using c++

Tags: c++, .net, windows

How to get windows dns suffix serach list from ip configuration using c++ ? (.NET <= 3.5)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get them from the registry.

If set from the network control panel:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Tcpip\Parameters\SearchList
```

If set by Group Policy:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\DNSClient\SearchList
```

Use the [Registry class to read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/microsoft.win32.registry.getvalue.aspx), the same class can be use set but, you will need admin permissions to do so.

C# using Management and WMI Classes:

```
ManagementObjectSearcher q= new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT ServiceName,DNSDomainSuffixSearchOrder FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");// WHERE DNSDomainSuffixSearchOrder IS NOT NULL");
var qc= q.Get();

foreach (ManagementObject mo in qc)
{
    if ( mo.Properties["DNSDomainSuffixSearchOrder"] != null)
    {
        var s = mo.Properties["DNSDomainSuffixSearchOrder"];
        if (s.Value != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(mo["ServiceName"]);
            string[] sfxNames = s.Value as string[];
            foreach (string sx in sfxNames)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(sx);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems right, found them... but really there is no winapi (other than register) to that ? like something less "origin of set" dependent?

Comment: Is suspect there is a bit of disconnection between Windows and the network. It not normal to worry about the suffix, you just ask for an endpoint at an address, the rest is 'magic'

Comment: You can also use WMI to query and set, c# added to the answer but should be easy enough to translate to c++.net

Comment: Thanks for these solutions.  I've created PowerShell commands based on this info / sharing here in case that helps others: https://gist.github.com/JohnLBevan/95f5b08400dea3607ec65fcdcfa09bdf/